# Constructing a one-to-one correspondence between closed interval and half open interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Construct a one-to-one correspondence between the closed interval $ [0,1] $ and the half-open interval $ [0,1)$.

Hint: Take $B=\{1\}$

Comment: Hint: Since the image of a compact set by a continuous function is compact too, our required map cannot be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to show that an infinite set that *looks* bigger than a second one might still have a bijection to it. This is easier to see for countable sets:

You can start by sending the infinite set $\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$ to $\{1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$ ... Can you do that? Have you heard of the hotel with infinitely many rooms where one new customer arrives..?

After that what should happen for the rest of the points?

Comment: I can not understand......and I do not know how to make solution of this question,

Comment: Try this link about the infinite hotel...: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_infinity

Answer (score 1):

Let $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}=\{q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots\}$ such that $q_1=1$. Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1)$ defined as follows $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is irrational, and $f(q_i)=q_{i+1}$ on the rational numbers. This is a direct application of Hilbert's Hotel.