# Give an example of a real valued function on $[0,1]$ satisfying the following property.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

My whole question looks like-
Give an example of a real valued function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ which satisfies the following property-
For each $y\in\Bbb{R}$ either there is no $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=y$ or there is exactly two points(say $x_1, x_2$) such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$.
Can anybody give such example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a function which is symmetric, and nearly works - for example has a single minimum, but doubles for all the other values. (a $v$ or $u$ shape will work). Then choose a symmetric set of points which is countably infinite, and includes the minimum point. Undefine the function at those points, and order them and find a way of allocating one value to the first two, a second to the next two etc. I think that could be made definite.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is not assumed to be continuous then the answer is yes. You could start this by defining a bijection between $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ as indicated in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1216066/25959).

If $f$ is continuous then the answer is "no, such a counterexample cannot exist."

By the extreme value theorem, $f$ attains its maximum. Call the two points which attain the maximum $x=a,b$. Then again by EVT, $f|_{[a,b]}$ attains its minimum on $[a,b]$, call it $m$. It is achieved at some $x=c,d$ satisfying
$$
a<c<d<b.
$$

Once more by the EVT, $f|_{[c,d]}$ attains its maximum, call it $M$, on $[c,d]$.

Now (you can show) by the intermediate value theorem, the value $\frac{m+M}{2}$ is attained at least four times on $[0,1]$, a contradiction. And if any of this unclear try drawing pictures of $a, b$, etc.

Comment: But I think you are assuming $f$ to be continuous. Because you are using EVT, and IVP. I am sure that this kind of function is not continuous. Can we get a direct example? A symmetric map may be a little hint(u and v shaped) But in my opinion, this kind of function should have uncountably many discontinuities(although I'm not 100% sure, I haven't proved it, just an intuition).

Comment: Agreed - I edited the first sentence to indicate how to construct an example in the noncontinuous case. After constructing the bijection, call an element of [0,1/2] x, and let $y$ be the corresponding point in $(1/2,1]$. Then assign $f(x)=f(y)=x$, which is the desired counterexample.

The continuous case I thought about because the question had the "continuity" tag!